# Get Hidden Field Value from Active jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, accordion

I am using MVC with C#.

I need to get the value from the hidden field of the active accordion in $(document).ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accordion doesn't add the class selected, but ui-accordion-content-active.

Try:

```
alert('value ' + $('.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active input[name$=EId]').val());
```

Comment: I m still getting undefined after trying this option too.

it returns an object when i used 
$('.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active input[name=EId]');

but it says undefined on getting the val() of that object.

Comment: This worked when i used like this

alert('value ' + $('.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active input[name$=EId]')[0].value);

Comment: are there more than one hidden fields that have names ending with EId?
If there are try $('.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active input[name$=EId]:first').val() (or replace the :first with :eq(0) (returns element with that zero-index index of the list of elements its selected)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing in more detail what your actual code is like, this is the closest guess I can give:

```
$(".ui-accordion .selected input[type=hidden]").val();
```

jQuery UI accordions have a "ui-accordion" class and automatically apply the "selected" class to the currently expanded accordion element.

Comment: Below is the code that i am referring:

<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <%if (Model != null){foreach (EmpDetails _emp in Model.EmpList){%>
    <h3>
        <div class="heading_acc">
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:ShowEmployees(<%=_emp.EmpID%>);"
                id="aE"><b><span class="dash_title_bar_right">
                    <%=Html.Encode(_emp.EmpName)%></b></a>
            <%=Html.Hidden("EId",_emp.EmpID,new {id="EId"})%>
        </div>
    </h3>
    <div id="dR<%=_emp.EmpID %>">
        <%=Html.Encode(_emp.EmpName)%>
    </div>
    <%}} %>
</div>

Comment: i Used 
alert($(".ui-accordion .selected input[name$='EId']").val());

It Shows undefined.

Comment: Try alert($(".ui-accordion .selected input[name=Eld]").val())

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this "strangeness" with jQuery; it seems the selector is returning an array of objects so you have to use the "[0]" to get the element you are looking for.